# How to select all the records even if there is no data in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a query like

```
SELECT  'Education' as Purpose,ate_sex, Age_range, COUNT(*) AS Total
  FROM (
        SELECT dbo.ClientMain.ate_sex, dbo.ClientMain.ate_Id, 
          CASE
            WHEN ate_Age BETWEEN 15 AND 19 THEN '15-19'
            WHEN ate_Age BETWEEN 20 AND 24 THEN '20-24'
            WHEN ate_Age BETWEEN 25 AND 34 THEN '25-34'
            WHEN ate_Age BETWEEN 35 AND 44 THEN '35-44'
            WHEN ate_Age BETWEEN 45 AND 54 THEN '45-54' 
            WHEN ate_Age BETWEEN 55 AND 64 THEN '55-64'
            ELSE '80+' END AS Age_range
         FROM dbo.ClientMain 
         INNER JOIN dbo.ClientSub ON dbo.ClientMain.ate_Id = dbo.ClientSub.ate_Id
         WHERE (dbo.ClientSub.chk_Name = N'Assistance')
       ) AS t group by ate_sex,Age_range
```

Which returns the data as:

[image]

But I want my result as when there is no record with he age range in 15-19, it have to return zero. As **Education     Male       15-19       0**
These are my tables
[image]
Can anybody please modify my query to get zeros for no records.

Comment: Please, provide an example of ClientMain and ClientSub rows.

Comment: Do you have any rows for ate_sex='Male' for 15-19 in your ClientMain table? If yes, you may want to use LEFT JOIN instead of Inner join.

Comment: See my table structure..@Francesco De Lisi

Comment: @NareshJadapalli I gave you the answer (or at least what you should use, which is better than a complete working query which won't teach you how to do these things in the future)

Comment: do you expect following three rows to be included in output ??           "Education Male 80+ 0 " , "Education Female 80+ 0 " , "Education Others 80+ 0 "

Comment: Yes.. If records are not there those have to come like that.. @Dhaval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`
- Use `ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0)` instead of `COUNT(*)`. Alternatively, you can also use

  `Total = CASE WHEN COUNT(*) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(*) END`

Comment: 'NONULL' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: I tried this.. event I am getting the same answer.. I am not getting zeros

Comment: Did you do the `LEFT JOIN`?

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
case when COUNT(*) = 1 then 0 else COUNT(*) end as exp
```

Comment: It is giving zeros for existed rows alsoo.. When the totals is 1 it is displaying as 0. If the total is more than 1 it is showing exact output

Comment: Noo.. I dint get any answer

Answer (score 0):

If you doesnt have data with male, 15-19 in any table, yet you still want it in result with count as "0". Try building a static table with possible rows and do a cross join with your resultset.